# writing current date & time as file name using NSIS

Tags: nsis

I developed an installer using [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page). Every time I re-install the application, I want to create a backup of the existing database files.

How can I rename these database files using the following format 'currentdatetime'(ex: 201003101140 means 2010-03-10 at 11:40 AM)?

Thanks !

Answer (score 20):

There is a built-in function in NSIS for this called ${GetTime}

```
  !include "FileFunc.nsh"
  !insertmacro GetTime

  ${GetTime} "" "L" $0 $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6
  DetailPrint "currentdatetime=$2$1$0$4$5$6"
```

This will output something like

```
  currentdatetime=20130210205537
```

meaning "10-Feb-2013 20:55:37".

Answer (score 6):

```
System::Call '*(&i2,&i2,&i2,&i2,&i2,&i2,&i2,&i2)i.s'
System::Call /NOUNLOAD 'kernel32::GetLocalTime(isr0)'
System::Call '*$0(&i2.r1,&i2.r2,&i2,&i2.r3,&i2.r4,&i2.r5,&i2,&i2)'
System::Free $0
IntFmt $1 "%0.4d" $1
IntFmt $2 "%0.2d" $2
IntFmt $3 "%0.2d" $3
IntFmt $4 "%0.2d" $4
IntFmt $5 "%0.2d" $5
DetailPrint "datetime=$1$2$3$4$5"
```

Answer (score 6):

The best way to do this is explained here: [nsis](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Date_and_time_in_installer_or_application_name)

    `!define /date MyTIMESTAMP "%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S"
    Name "MyApplicationName ${MyTIMESTAMP}"
    OutFile "MyApplicationNameSetup-${MyTIMESTAMP}.exe"`

Comment: This is a compile time command, not runtime, so the date given by ``${MyTIMESTAMP}`` will be that of the _build_ not when run. This will not work to create a backup folder.

Comment: This was exactly what I looked for

Answer (score -1):

These macros might work for you: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter5.html#5.2.3