# How to prefix log entries generated from NSIS exe with current date and time without overwriting registers?

Tags: nsis

I want to write timestamps at the start of each line entered into a log during the run of an NSIS (Nullsoft) .exe program.

It appears the only valid pattern to call the GetTime function is:
${GetTime} "" "L" $0 $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6

This results in overwriting the registers ($0, $1, etc.) in the calling .nsh files. Is there a way to prevent this?

For example:

The global_defines.nsh contains something like this:

```
!macro WriteLog text
...
  FileWrite $mylogfile '${text}'
  ${GetTime} "" "L" $0 $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6
  FileWrite $mylogfile "$2-$1-$0 $4:$5:$6 '${text}'"
...
```

and the calling .nsh file contains something like this:

```
StrCpy $1 'run_this_script'
!insertmacro WriteLog "About to run: $1"
ExecDos::exec /TOWINDOW $1
pop $0
!insertmacro WriteLog "script run returned $0"
```

This results in $1 getting set to the month value set in the macro.

A separate posting:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19622151/6388369
shows using $year, etc., but this does not compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$year` is a custom variable:

```
Var year

Section
${GetTime} ... $year ...
FileWrite ...
SectionEnd
```

The other alternative is to save/restore the old data if you need to preserve it (which you usually need to do in helper macros):

```
Section
Push $0
Push $1
Push ...
${GetTime} ... $0 $1 ...
FileWrite ...
Pop ...
Pop $1
Pop $0
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Thanks.  That solved it.
I set up the global variables:

`
Var day
Var month
Var year
Var day_name
Var hour
Var minute
Var seconds
`

and then used this code (snippet):

`
{GetTime} "" "L" $day $month $year $day_name $hour $minute $seconds
FileWrite $mylogfile "$year-$month-$day $hour:$minute:$seconds '${text}'"
`